# How can I find matching inputs from Array using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a very simple array here:

```
var myArray = [
            "ca_1_50_max":6
            "ca_1_50_min":4
            "ca_2_40_max":6
            "ca_2_40_min":4
            "ca_3_30_max":6
            "ca_3_30_min":4
            "ca_4_20_max":6
            "ca_4_20_min":4
            "ca_5_10_max":6
            "ca_5_10_min":4
            "ca_6_0_max":6
            "ca_6_0_min":4
        ];
```

I have text inputs with matching ID's. Unfortunately I don't have access to the HTML. How can I append these as data attributes to my inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" data-ca_6_0_min="4" data-ca_6_0_max="6">
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in javascript, you might have an object, but not an array literal with properties. please add a valid data structure.

Comment: I don't see the ID in your HTML. Also, as Nina has mentioned, your array syntax is incorrect.

Comment: How are you supposed to know which inputs to add the data attributes to?

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm wondering Nina where did you collect all of your knowledge, on many posts I red I saw your great & beautiful comments, it's awesome to read that you know what you'r talking about! Do you have any tips for us beginners how to achieve some decent level of knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

if you will change your data... 
for example:

```
var myArray = [
{"data" : "ca_1_50_max",
"val" : 6},
{"data" : "ca_1_50_min",
"val" : 4},
{"data" : "ca_1_50_max",
"val" : 6},
{"data" : "ca_1_50_max",
"val" : 6},
{"data" : "ca_1_50_max",
"val" : 6},
{"data" : "ca_1_50_max",
"val" : 6}]
```

Then you will be able to call it for example

> myArray[0].data

- it will generate 1 data value from your array

> myArray[0].val

- it will generate 1 value from your array

Now you need to create inputs...
You can do it like that:

```
var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
    x.setAttribute(myArray[0].data, myArray[0].val);
    x.setAttribute(myArray[1].data, myArray[1].val);

    document.body.appendChild(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the curly braces (object) for multidimensional array declaration:

```
var myArray = {"ca_1_50_max":6,"ca_1_50_min":4 ... }
```

```js
  var myArray = {
            "ca_1_50_max":6,
            "ca_1_50_min":4,
            "ca_2_40_max":6,
            "ca_2_40_min":4,
            "ca_3_30_max":6,
            "ca_3_30_min":4,
            "ca_4_20_max":6,
            "ca_4_20_min":4,
            "ca_5_10_max":6,
            "ca_5_10_min":4,
            "ca_6_0_max":6,
            "ca_6_0_min":4
        };
for(var key in myArray){
   $('input').attr(key, myArray[key]);
}
console.log($('input')[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" data-ca_6_0_min="4" data-ca_6_0_max="6">
```